# How do you convert an array of ObjectIds into an array of embedded documents with a field containing the original array element value

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents where one of the fields is currently an array of ObjectId items.

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    user: "jdoe",
    docs: [
        ObjectId(1),
        ObjectId(2),
        ...
    ]
}
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    user: "jsmith",
    docs: [
        ObjectId(3),
        ObjectId(4),
        ...
    ]
}
```

How can I update all of the documents in my collection to convert the docs field into an array of objects that contain a "docID" field equal to the original element value?

For example, I'd want my documents to end up looking like:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    user: "jdoe",
    docs: [
        { docID: ObjectId(1) },
        { docID: ObjectId(2) },
        ...
    ]
}
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    user: "jsmith",
    docs: [
        { docID: ObjectId(3)},
        { docID: ObjectId(4)},
        ...
    ]
}
```

I'm hoping there is a command that I can run from the shell such as:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').update(
    {}, 
    { 
        $set: { 
            'docs.$[]: { docID: '$$VALUE'}
        }
    }, 
    {multi: true }
);
```

But I can't figure out how to reference the original value of the element.

---

**Update:**

I'm marking @mickl with the correct answer since it got me on the correct track.  Below is the final aggregate that I ended up with which ***only changes the docs field if it is an array of object IDs, otherwise the existing value is left as-is, including documents that don't have a docs field.***

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    { $addFields: {
        'docs': { $cond: {
            if : { $eq: [{ $type: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$docs', 0]} }, "objectId"]},
            then: { $map: {
                input: '$docs',
                in: { tocID: '$$this'}
            }},
            else : '$docs'
        }}
    }},
    { $out: "myCollection" }
])
```

Comment: You can use `$out` aggregation here. `db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
 { "$addFields": {
  "docs": {
   "$map": {
    "input": "$docs",
    "in": { "docID": "$$this" }
   }
  }
 }},
 { "$out": "newCollection" }
])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to reshape your data and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to replace existing collection with aggregation result:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            docs: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$docs",
                    in: { docID: "$$this" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $out: "col" }
])
```

Comment: Thanks @mickl.  Since not all of my documents have the docs field, I had avoided the aggregate $out approach because I didn't want to accidentally lose some of the original docs.  $out makes me nervous... looking forward to the upcoming $merge stage.  I guess I'll just have to do several dry runs to make sure my aggregate pipeline includes all documents and modifies those that do have the docs field.

Comment: @JerrenSaunders you can specify temporary collection as $out parameter, verify the output and then overwrite existing one

Comment: Yes that is my current approach.  Thanks for the guidance.